# Best way to insert special characters to the webpage

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm building a website where user wants to input special characters in search box (symbols like áèíμô). What is the best way to implement that? Is there any shortcut like javascript popup window with all of theese characters and user can just select desired character?

Comment: Typing them should be up to the user. Just make sure your app can handle the input correctly.

Comment: My app can handle the input very well, but my customer want this feature. He saw it on MS Word :D He want to input some special characters, but he hasn't these characters on his keyboard.

Comment: Sometimes, it is our professional responsibility as developers to say "no, that's a bad idea". Teach how to type them on their keyboard - it's just a special key combination. There's also, IIRC, a tool in Windows to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Users wanting to enter those characters will usually have a keyboard (or other method) that allows them to enter them already.

A custom solution that only works for your website is likely to be counterproductive. If a user can't enter the characters already, then the odds are they will need a solution they can use outside of your website too.

So you can use a plain text input.

```
<input>
```

Comment: Well, my users don't have those characters on their keyboard.

Comment: They can reconfigure their keyword in their system settings and learn where the characters they want are. They can use an onscreen keyboard or character finder (one probably came with their operating system). A solution specific to a single website is still unlikely to be a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

if you want a shortcut you can use virtual keyboard plugin for jQuery and define your own characters on the keyboard, user can reveal the virtual keyboard and click the character

take a look at Custom: Mapped Keys here:

https://mottie.github.io/Keyboard/